# Clone Flash Drive in Linux using DD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, copy, clone, dd

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

I want to create a clone a bootable USB stick.

lets say sda is 2GB
sdb is 32GB.

The above line will create a replica but the usable size will be 2GB. How can I use the remaining 30GB? (resize partition or modify the command so that it will maximize the usable space)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** When you copy the drive instead of the partition, the partition-table gets overwritten and it might not be possible to make the partion bigger afterwards because the partition-table says that the disksize is only 2GB. On the other hand, if you copy only the data of the partition, the bootloader will break. You might want to have a different filesystem (e.g. ext3 instead of fat32), then dd won't work and you have to use cp.

ArchLinux wiki has an excellent [tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_Cloning#Using_cp) for this.

Now you have to reinstall grub2 bootloader to your disks mbr (not the partition): [tutorial](http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/p20/GRUB2%20Bash%20Commands.html#GRUB_USB)

If you're still having problems, this might help: [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5297/debian-grub2-moving-root-partition-to-new-drive)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `dd` to make and apply your disk image, you will then need to use a partition management tool like `gparted` to expand the partition after it has been applied to the larger destination disk.

Comment: thats what I thought but I was hoping for a linux trick that would do both in 1 step. Thanks

Comment: dd doesn't know anything about filesystems and partitions.  You'll need a tool that knows something about those things to manipulate them.

Comment: @CocoaDev IF you write zeros to empty space before cloning with `dd`, you can then compress the dd file rather nicely.

Comment: You could use gparted to close the disk and resize, and skip the dd step.

Comment: If you want to do this all from a script, you can - but you'll need to know what filesystem is on sda. Then you can use the right tool - extresize, ntfsresize, etc.

Comment: The filesystem I am using is FAT16

Comment: @CocoaDev FAT16 has an [architectural filesystem size limit of 2 GB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/118335/en-us). So no luck with resizing then.

Comment: After cloning, you can always convert the FileSystem to NTFS using the convert command in Windows

Comment: Does gparted ship with Ubuntu 11.1?